# Excel VBA XMLHTTP

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to add some stuff automatically to my cart. This should work until the Page switch.  How can I refresh the HTML Code?

```
Dim Page As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTML As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim Btn As Object

Page.Open "GET", "https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00IPH78O6/ref=ox_sc_act_image_1?smid=A1JZY7TFGMYK57&psc=1", False
Page.send

HTML.body.innerHTML = Page.responseText
Set Btn = HTML.getElementById("add-to-cart-button")
Btn.Click

HTML.body.innerHTML = Page.responseText
Set Btn = HTML.getElementById("hlb-view-cart-announce")
Btn.Click
```

Comment: Is the issue that you're trying to refresh the page, or get an updated copy of the page into a variable?  What is the specific problem?

Comment: Yes i try to refreh the current html code. After the first Button is clicked the Page change to a different one. When i try to find the next Button it did not exist because the page.responseText got the old Page saved

Comment: And how did you execute this line `Btn.Click`? You are not working with IE, right? At least your script doesn't say so.

Comment: Yes the Script do not open IE, i got a working IE version but it is so slow.. Thats why i try to get this none IE version running..

Comment: @ashleedawg it should click "Einkaufswagen" http://fs5.directupload.net/images/180527/8vle9wlz.png

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the method you're using; I woudl probably stick with the InternetExplorer object.  The issue wasn't IE - it was a coding issue.  For example, you say it "did not open IE", you would have needed to tell it to display the window, with something like "ie.Visible = True".  Have you looked through the [IE/VBA questions/answers on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=internet+explorer+vba+click)?

Comment: The thing is 5 Loops take about 3-5 Minutes with the IE Code, finally it should have more then 30 Loops so i try to avoid IE if possible..

Comment: @cYc2k -  If coded correctly, it will take the same amount of time (or more likely less time) than if you open IE and do the same actions manually.

Comment: @ashleedawg what do you mean "correctly"?

Comment: It was a broad statement, and that's a very broad reply, but basically I mean *"properly, as per documentation, efficiently.  Free of bugs and unnecessary code. Variables properly declared; Objects properly created, handled & disposed-of"..*  etc etc etc

Comment: My IE Code looks like:             IE.Visible = True
            IE.Navigate Produkt
            Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    
            Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
            HTMLDoc.getElementById("add-to-cart-button").Click
            Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

Comment: You can't add fixed wait time and expect code to run smoothly. there already is a loop to make IE wait. Will code still work properly if `Application.Wait` is removed or some JavaScript needs this additional time?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [selenium basic](http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/) e.g.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver '<== You can change to other supported browsers e.g. IE, FireFox

    With d
         .Start "Chrome"
         .Get "https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00IPH78O6/ref=nav_signin?smid=A1JZY7TFGMYK57&psc=1&"
         .FindElementById("add-to-cart-button").Click
         .FindElementById("hlb-view-cart-announce").Click

         'Other stuff '<== Delete this line

         '.Quit
   End With

End Sub
```

The method you are currently trying would require you to issue new requests and on there being a method you could replicate that navigates the different pages. You could try monitoring with Fiddler or a similar tool but I would just go with Selenium.

Comment: Thanks i take a look :-)

Comment: I got an error with Selenium in the Start Line: http://fs1.directupload.net/images/180527/gipatxqi.png

Comment: On what line? And did you add the tools > references > selenium type library?

Comment: Do you have chrome installed?

Comment: The Error plos up at the Line .Start "Chrome". Yeah i added the reference for Selenium: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/180527/7sqrrq6i.png - and sure i got the Chrome Broswer installed, start chrome opens the Browser with "data:," in the url field

Comment: So basically seems like some kind of timeout error. Does it happen each time you try run? It may be to do with the URL string. Have you tried adapting to run with the URL you would get with your account logged in?

Comment: if i try to run www.google.com the same error appears.the url will not entered in the browser, i also tryed another browser and .Start "Chrome", "www.google.de"

Comment: Try with FireFox or IE driver? See if it is perhaps a security setting. Some example connections from the author https://pastebin.com/HX8HPqpr

Comment: Still having issues with this?